# KB4571703 doesn't fix ZeroLogon

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows server 2012 R2 and would like to apply the patch to fix ZeroLogon issue (CVE-2020-1472). So I download `KB4571703` from [Windows Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4571703), then install it using following steps:

```
1.expand _f:* “C:\Temp\kb4571703.msu” C:\Temp\kb4571703  
2.cd C:\Temp\kb4571703
3.dism /online /add-package /packagepath:Windows8.1-KB4571703-x64.cab
4.restart-computer
```

I check the Installed Updates from Control Panel, I can see `KB4571703` is installed.

Then, I double-check it by running the script provied by [SecuraBV](https://github.com/SecuraBV/CVE-2020-1472) and [picuslabs](https://github.com/picussecurity/picuslabs/tree/master/CVE-2020-1472%20Zerologon), but whatever I've tried, the script always return message "Success! DC can be fully compromised by a Zerologon attack.", which means the vulnerability still exists!

That was really confused me, so I enable the log of NetLogon to dig into the details, here are some parts of logs:

> 16:29:10 [CRITICAL] [644] NetrServerAuthenticate: Bad password 0
> for Corey-AD-1 on account Corey-AD-1$
> 16:29:10 [CRITICAL] [644] NetrServerAuthenticate: Bad password 0 for Corey-AD-1 on account Corey-AD-1$
> 16:29:10 [CRITICAL] [644] NetrServerAuthenticate: Bad password 0 for Corey-AD-1 on account Corey-AD-1$
> 16:29:10 [CRITICAL] [644] NetrServerAuthenticate: Bad password 0 for Corey-AD-1 on account Corey-AD-1$
> 16:29:10 [MISC] [644] Eventlog: 5805 (1) "Corey-AD-1" 0xc0000022 2f8270f1 5bc8d5e7 34c3e164 6665df64 .p./...[d..4d.ef
> 16:29:10 [CRITICAL] [644] NlTransportLookup: \\Corey-AD-1: Cannot NetSessionEnum 2312
> 16:29:10 [SESSION] [644] NetrServerAuthenticate returns Success: Corey-AD-1 on account Corey-AD-1$ (Negot: 212fffff)

As you can see, the service returns Success at the end, it means the attack was successful. But why? I already patched `KB4571703` on my Windows server 2012 R2, what causes this happen?

**Update 19/11/2020**

I can't find any log with Event ID 5827, 5828, 5829, 5830, and 5831 in `Event Viewer > Windows Logs > System` after applying the patch `KB4571703` or `KB4577066`.

I can't find the setting "Domain controller: Allow vulnerable Netlogon secure channel connections" in Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options either.

Comment: The update in question was replaced by KB4577066 try installing it

Comment: @Ramhound Applied KB4577066 but nothing changed, test script still returns "it can be fully compromised by a Zerologon".

Comment: Did you enabled enforcement mode?

Comment: @Ramhound Added `FullSecureChannelProtection` as 1 in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters and restart my server, but nothing changed.

Comment: [I must have missed that on the page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4557222/how-to-manage-the-changes-in-netlogon-secure-channel-connections-assoc).  Just to make sure, since you had installed the previous patch, you have read those instructions?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for sharing. However, I can't find any log with Event ID 5827, 5828, 5829, 5830, and 5831 in Event Viewer > Windows Logs > System, weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116401/discussion-between-corey-and-ramhound).